# Syntax highlighting in minted - how does it work?

Tags: minted, python

I want to customize the `minted` syntax highlighting, but neither the [`minted` package documentation](http://get-software.net/macros/latex2e/contrib/minted/minted.pdf), nor the [existing topics on syntax highlighting in minted on TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=syntax%20highlighting%20minted), nor [google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=syntax%20highlighting%20in%20minted) offer explanation on how to do this.

I'm not really convinced yet that `minted` is so superior to `listings`, an opinion that finds its inception mostly in the on-the-fly customizability of `listings`.

Therefore two questions:

1. Why should I use `minted` over another package if its flexibility and accessibility of customization leaves so much to be desired?
2. Where do I adjust the syntax highlighting colours for the `minted` package? Preferrably I'd like to be able to make my own colour scheme.

.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{ %
  backgroundcolor=\color{white},   % choose the background color; you must add \usepackage{color} or \usepackage{xcolor}
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,        % the size of the fonts that are used for the code
  breakatwhitespace=false,         % sets if automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace
  breaklines=true,                 % sets automatic line breaking
  captionpos=b,                    % sets the caption-position to bottom
  commentstyle=\color{red},    % comment style
  deletekeywords={...},            % if you want to delete keywords from the given language
  escapeinside={\%*}{*)},          % if you want to add LaTeX within your code
  extendedchars=true,              % lets you use non-ASCII characters; for 8-bits encodings only, does not work with UTF-8
  frame=single,                    % adds a frame around the code
  keepspaces=true,                 % keeps spaces in text, useful for keeping indentation of code (possibly needs columns=flexible)
  keywordstyle=\color{orange},       % keyword style
  language=R,                 % the language of the code
  morekeywords={*,...},            % if you want to add more keywords to the set
  numbers=left,                    % where to put the line-numbers; possible values are (none, left, right)
  numbersep=5pt,                   % how far the line-numbers are from the code
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{purple}, % the style that is used for the line-numbers
  rulecolor=\color{black},         % if not set, the frame-color may be changed on line-breaks within not-black text (e.g. comments (green here))
  showspaces=false,                % show spaces everywhere adding particular underscores; it overrides 'showstringspaces'
  showstringspaces=false,          % underline spaces within strings only
  showtabs=false,                  % show tabs within strings adding particular underscores
  stepnumber=2,                    % the step between two line-numbers. If it's 1, each line will be numbered
  stringstyle=\color{green},     % string literal style
  tabsize=1,                       % sets default tabsize to 2 spaces
  title=\lstname                   % show the filename of files included with \lstinputlisting; also try caption instead of title
}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{fruity}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
/* Block
 * comment */
int main()
{
    int i;
    // Line comment.
    puts("Hello world!");

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        puts("LaTeX is also great for programmers!");
    }
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\begin{minted}{python}
import numpy as np
def incmatrix(genl1,genl2):
    m = len(genl1)
    n = len(genl2)
    M = None #to become the incidence matrix
    VT = np.zeros((n*m,1), int)  #dummy variable
    #compute the bitwise xor matrix
    M1 = bitxormatrix(genl1)
    M2 = np.triu(bitxormatrix(genl2),1) 
...
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `minted` works through [Pygments](http://pygments.org/); to see how to customise the highlighting with your own colour scheme, read its documentation.

Comment: Customizing `minted` highlighting requires customizing Pygments.  You would want to look at the [documentation](http://pygments.org/docs/plugins/).  Looking at some existing style extensions might also be useful (possibilities that a quick search revealed [here](https://github.com/shkumagai/pygments-style-solarized/tree/develop/pygments_style_solarized) and [here](https://github.com/hugomaiavieira/pygments-style-github/blob/master/pygments_style_github/__init__.py)).